# Limiting table to amount of records that have specific value in one of columns

Tags: mysql, sql

My task is to select countries whose amount of cities is higher than the amount of cities that have Canada as a country in the table. I'm using city and country tables from **sakila database**. Now, I've got something like this:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(country) FROM ( city
  INNER JOIN country ON country.country_id = city.country_id)
  GROUP BY country
  HAVING COUNT(country) >= 7 -- should be COUNT(country='Canada') or something like that
  ORDER BY COUNT(country) DESC;
```

Number 7 in 4th line is amount of cities, where country column equals 'Canada' but I have no idea how to count that using SQL nor could I find a correct way using google. Any suggestions?

Comment: HAVING COUNT(case when country = 'Canada' then 1 end) >= 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to put a subquery into your HAVING clause.

The following query gets the number of cities in canada.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM city
LEFT JOIN country ON city.country_id = country.country_id
WHERE country = 'Canada'
GROUP BY country
```

So you put this into your having clause.

```
SELECT 
    country, COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    city
INNER JOIN 
    country ON country.country_id = city.country_id
GROUP BY 
    country
HAVING 
    COUNT(country) >= (
        SELECT count(*) 
        FROM city
        LEFT JOIN country ON city.country_id = country.country_id
        WHERE country = 'Canada'
        GROUP BY country
    )
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(country) DESC;
```